# Compare all lists within list of lists based on condition and group them together by their difference

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have the following list of lists:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5], [4,5,6,7,8], [1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7,8,9], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [6,7,8,9], [5,6,7,8,9], [2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6], [11,12,13,14,15], [13,14,15]]
```

Representing them with their index for easy understanding:

```
0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
2 [1, 2, 3, 4]
3 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
4 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
5 [6, 7, 8, 9]
6 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
7 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
8 [3, 4, 5, 6]
9 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
10 [13, 14, 15]
```

I'm expecting the output which will be a list of tuples like below:

```
output = [(0,2,1), (3,1,1), (4,7,2), (4,1,2), (6,5,1), (3,5,2), (3,6,1), (7,8,1), (9,10,2)]

For example to explain first item of output i.e, (0,2,1):

0 ---> index of list under comparison with highest length 
2 ---> index of list under comparison with lowest length
1 ---> difference in length of the two lists 0 & 2
```

Now, coming to the problem:

I have lists which have similar items which differ by length of one and two (or three) at start or end the lists.

I want to sort, group, identify the index of lists and their difference as a tuple.

I went through multiple stackoverflow questions, but couldn't find a similar question.

I'm new to python and started with the following codes in bits and got stuck:

```
a = sorted(a, key = len)

incr = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(a, key=len)]

decr = list(reversed(incr))

ndecr = [i for j in decr for i in j]

for i in range(len(ndecr)-1):
    if len(ndecr[i]) - len(ndecr[i+1]) == 1:
        print(ndecr[i])

for i in range(len(ndecr)-2):
    if len(ndecr[i]) - len(ndecr[i+2]) == 2:
        print(ndecr[i])

for i in ndecr:
    ele = i
    ndecr.remove(i)
    for j in ndecr:
        if ele[:-1] == j:
            print(j)   

for i in ndecr:
    ele = i
    ndecr.remove(i)
    for j in ndecr:
        if ele[:-2] == j:
            print(i)
```

Please help me with the approach I should take in achieving the output.

Comment: What exactly do you want to "sort" and "group" in your output? I think I understand that you want to compare all the lists in your list of lists and output the indices of the compared lists along with the difference in lengths, but I am not sure how you want the output sorted or grouped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, assuming that the total number of lists is small so that len(lists)^2 is still small, something like

```
from itertools import combinations

# sort by length but preserve the index
ax = sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))

done = []

for (i0, seq0), (i1, seq1) in combinations(ax, 2):
    if seq1[:len(seq0)] == seq0 or seq1[-len(seq0):] == seq0:
       done.append((i1, i0, len(seq1)-len(seq0)))
```

gives me

```
In [117]: sorted(done)
Out[117]: 
[(0, 2, 1),
 (3, 1, 1),
 (3, 5, 2),
 (3, 6, 1),
 (4, 1, 2),
 (4, 7, 2),
 (6, 5, 1),
 (7, 8, 1),
 (9, 10, 2)]
```

which matches your output but for order, and for the fact you have (4, 7, 2) listed twice.

```
seq1[:len(seq0)] == seq0
```

is the "does seq1 start with seq0?" condition, and

```
seq1[-len(seq0):] == seq0
```

is the "does seq1 end with seq0?" condition.

Comment: Its a mistake. (4,7,2) repeated twice. Edited and removed it.

Comment: I need to learn more modules, I had to do this with enumerate I'm jealous

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (original below):

Now, I might be understanding you better (thanks to [@vash_the_stampede](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10255652/vash-the-stampede) for the clarifying comment). This approach nests a couple of loops to compare every list in your list of lists and determine whether one is a subset of the other. Then, if the compared lists are superset / subset, it creates an output list of tuples each containing the indices of two compared lists ordered longest first along with the difference in the lengths of those compared lists.

IMPORTANT: this approach does not compare list order, so it could provide output that you may not want like `[1,2,4,5]` is a subset of `[1,2,3,4,5]` with a length difference of 1. Or, specific to your example, this approach outputs an extra tuple when compared to your example output because `[3,4,5,6]`, at index 8, is a subset of `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, at index 4, with a length of difference of 3. I think the answer from [@DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) handles this issue, so it is probably closer to what you need.

Example output from your current dataset:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5], [4,5,6,7,8], [1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7,8,9], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [6,7,8,9], [5,6,7,8,9], [2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6], [11,12,13,14,15], [13,14,15]]

output = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
       if set(a[i]).issubset(a[j]) or set(a[i]).issuperset(a[j]):
           diff = abs(len(a[i]) - len(a[j]))
           if len(a[i]) > len(a[j]):
               output.append((i, j, diff))
           else:
               output.append((j, i, diff))

print(output)

# OUTPUT
# [(0, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1), (4, 1, 2), (3, 5, 2), (3, 6, 1), (4, 7, 2), (4, 8, 3), (6, 5, 1), (7, 8, 1), (9, 10, 2)]
```

ORIGINAL:

If I am understanding you correctly, then you can just nest a couple of loops to compare every list in your list of lists. Then, create an output list of tuples each containing the indices of two compared lists along with the difference in the lengths of those compared lists. For example:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5], [4,5,6,7,8], [1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7,8,9], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [6,7,8,9], [5,6,7,8,9], [2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6], [11,12,13,14,15], [13,14,15]]

output = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
       diff = abs(len(a[i]) - len(a[j]))
       output.append((i, j, diff))

print(output)

# OUTPUT
# [(0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 3, 1), (0, 4, 2), (0, 5, 1), (0, 6, 0), (0, 7, 0), (0, 8, 1), (0, 9, 0), (0, 10, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 2), (1, 5, 1), (1, 6, 0), (1, 7, 0), (1, 8, 1), (1, 9, 0), (1, 10, 2), (2, 3, 2), (2, 4, 3), (2, 5, 0), (2, 6, 1), (2, 7, 1), (2, 8, 0), (2, 9, 1), (2, 10, 1), (3, 4, 1), (3, 5, 2), (3, 6, 1), (3, 7, 1), (3, 8, 2), (3, 9, 1), (3, 10, 3), (4, 5, 3), (4, 6, 2), (4, 7, 2), (4, 8, 3), (4, 9, 2), (4, 10, 4), (5, 6, 1), (5, 7, 1), (5, 8, 0), (5, 9, 1), (5, 10, 1), (6, 7, 0), (6, 8, 1), (6, 9, 0), (6, 10, 2), (7, 8, 1), (7, 9, 0), (7, 10, 2), (8, 9, 1), (8, 10, 1), (9, 10, 2)]
```

Comment: Look at the instructions and ouput he only wants tuples that are comprised of lists that share same values but differ slightly, he does not all comparisons of all lists

Comment: @vash_the_stampede you might be getting a clearer picture of what OP wants than I am from the question as it currently stands. I posted a comment asking for more clarification after re-reading cause I am now a little hazy on what OP is after.

Comment: for instance `a[0]` is like `a[2]` but differs by one item, `5` so these two indexes become a tuple `(0,2,1)` , 1 being the amount number of items they differ by

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I'm sure this could be done more efficiently but what I did was create copies of the original list that where each item is shortened on either end by one or two, then compared those items and returned the indexes with the corresponding length they differed by, it works but its pretty big I'm going to see about reducing it

```
l1 = a[:]

tups = []
for idx, item in enumerate(l1):
    for x, i in enumerate(a):
        if sorted(item[:-1]) == sorted(i):
            tups.append((idx, x, 1))
        elif sorted(item[:-2]) == sorted(i):
            tups.append((idx, x, 2))
        elif sorted(item[1:]) == sorted(i):
            tups.append((idx, x, 1))
        elif sorted(item[2:]) == sorted(i):
            tups.append((idx, x, 2))

print(tups)
```

> ```
> [(0, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1), (4, 7, 2), (3, 6, 1), (6, 5, 1), (7, 8, 1), (3, 5, 2), (4, 1, 2), (9, 10, 2)]
> ```